# Select distinct columns for which all rows meet a condition

Tags: sql

I want to select the distinct `a, b`'s for which **all** the `c`'s have a specific value (in my case **null**)

So given the rows below

```
a   b   c
AN8 USD 99
AN8 USD 
AT0 EUR 
AT0 EUR
```

the result should be

```
a   b
AT0 EUR
```

I have failed to successfully translate that to a query, could you please help me out?

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: @Igor as I mention I didnt manage to have any meaningful results, that's why I omitted the code I have so far

Comment: GROUP BY/HAVING, or NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select a, b from foo group by a, b having bool_and(c is null);
```

where `bool_and` is a postgres aggregate function.

Or maybe this, should work with ANSI sql I think:

```
select a, b from foo group by a, b having count(c) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying some stuff with joins and subselections, this is much simpler

Answer (score 1):

If you `group by a, b` any aggregation function like `min()`, `max()`, `sum()` or even `avg()` on `c` returns `null` for the condition that you set:

```
select a, b
from tablename
group by a, b
having max(c) is null
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e21f729d17c12633b6f66f912548e3d).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below:

```
select a, b from table where c is NULL group by a, b having count(*)>1;
```

Comment: That returns the AN8, USD row too.

Comment: Just Updated @petre